# How can i solve attached Generated plugin Registertant error

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YCR3.jpg)      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin());

```
                                                                     ^
```

C:\Users\HODA\lala\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:24: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core does not exist

```
  flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());

                                                                     ^
```

2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details